# Regex number pattern and maxlength not working on IE

Tags: html, regex, webforms

Number pattern and max length are not working on IE.

I have tried variations of the below HTML, though IE appears to bypass that validation.

```
<input id="phone" maxlength="10" minlength="10" pattern="[0-9.]+" type="text">
```

Any suggestions on enforcing the above on IE?
The goal is to only allow 10-digits for that input field.

Comment: I don't have experience with webforms, but couldn't you just do this all with the regex pattern? `^[0-9.]{10}$`

Comment: Hi there! Is there any reason you're not using `<input type="tel"`, because this has an implicit regex which might sort you out! Your code would become: `<input id="phone" maxlength="10" minlength="10" type="tel">`

Comment: @CAustin this seems to work, is there away to customise the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use an `<input type="tel">` element, but it actually allows you to enter *any* characters. So, ultimately you need to specify a pattern and be very explicit as to what you are looking for and rely on HTML5 form validation. For example, if you are trying to input a phone number of the format `999.999.9999`, then you want a something like the following. If you enter something that does not match the pattern and try to submit the form by hitting enter, you will get an error indication. Of course, use whatever pattern you want. If you just want digits and decimal points in any order (why?) but they must be length 10, then use `pattern="[0-9.]{10}"`.

```html
 
<form>
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4}" required>
</form>
```